# What were the approximate ages of the heads of house(niseim) in parshat bamidbar. Above or below 60 years old

Tags: number, parsha-torah-portion, bamidbar-parsha

Having just read last weeks parsha bamidbar. I wanted to know approximately how old the heads of house  (niseim) of Israel were when the jews were counted. Were they older than 60 and they were not part of the census or between 20 and 60 and were part of the census.

Was just curious asked a few rabbis didnt get an answer yet.

Comment: Even if they were the right age they may not have been counted since they were the ones counting

Comment: Just curious what would make you think that they weren't counted. Do you have a source?

Comment: Rashi says Moshe and Aharon weren't counted with the leviim so could be similar

Comment: @DoubleAA he says Aharon wasn't counted, where does he say Moshe wasn't either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elishama ben Amihud was Yehoshua's grandfather (Divrei Hayamim 1:7:26-27), and Yehoshua was 58 years old at the time(*).  So at least one nasi was over 60.

(*) Yehoshua lived 110 years (Yehoshua 24:29).  This was 14 years after going into Eretz Yisrael, and the count was 38 years before that.  So he was around 110 - 14 - 38 = 58, +/- a year because I'm not sure when his birthday and yahrtzeit were, but that doesn't affect the overall picture.